# How to avoid printing None by aws CLI when no data found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm searching for values in DynamoDB like this:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name table --key '{"name": {"S":"test"}}' --output text --query Item.value
```

If the item was not found, it prints `None`. How to avoid that and print an empty string instead?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a default empty string value if nothing was found for the `Item.value` you are looking for:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name table --key '{"name": {"S":"test"}}' --output text --query 'Item.value || ``'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could re-direct to `/dev/null`?

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name table --key '{"name": {"S":"test"}}' --output text --query Item.value > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Be careful, because by doing so, you redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`. So if there is some error, you won't see it.